# Magento Category Thumbnail Missing

Tags: magento

I'm moving my first steps on magento cms but cannot understand why in local installation with xampp i can insert the thumbnail from the backend while in server installation i dont' have the field to upload the thumbnail of the category.
[image: Magento on server]

Thx all!
Alex

Screen of local installation 
[image: Magento on local]

Comment: Very interested in an answer for this question. I too do not see a method of adding a thumbnail image, where I used to with the sample installation of magento. I'm sporting magento 1.9.10.

Comment: I had lost a lot of time to find the way to solve problem , however I am not a php programmer. The only solution for me was to install magento 1.9.0 where thumbnail upload work perfectly from backend. Still have not figured out if it is a bug in version 1.9.1 !

Comment: I've done a bit more specific searching and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264466/magento-category-thumbnail-field-not-show-in-admin/27878753#27878753. I will look into it at work tomorrow.