# Magento category thumbnail field not shown in admin

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I have installed Magento 1.9.1.0 without sample data but in admin, add or edit category page have no thumbnail image field. How can I show thumbnail filed in admin for category?
[image]

Comment: did you find the answer, I have same issue

Comment: Not still. But for get the thumbnail field, I just install with sample data and then truncate the products, categories, orders and attributes tables. By this data removed and thumbnail field remain visible

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this issue via running the following queries in my phpMyAdmin,

1)

```
 INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, 
`attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, 
`frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, 
`is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES(140, 3, 'thumbnail', NULL, 
 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'image', 'Thumbnail
 Image', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

2)

```
 INSERT INTO `catalog_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `frontend_input_renderer`, 
`is_global`, `is_visible`, `is_searchable`, `is_filterable`, `is_comparable`, 
`is_visible_on_front`, `is_html_allowed_on_front`, `is_used_for_price_rules`, 
`is_filterable_in_search`, `used_in_product_listing`, `used_for_sort_by`, 
`is_configurable`, `apply_to`, `is_visible_in_advanced_search`, `position`, 
`is_wysiwyg_enabled`, `is_used_for_promo_rules`) VALUES 
 (140, NULL, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

3)

```
INSERT INTO `eav_entity_attribute` (`entity_attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`,  
`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_id`, `attribute_id`, `sort_order`) 
VALUES (337, 3, 3, 4, 140, 3);
```

Here i am using attribute_id as 140,use an id for this in these queries by a unique value

Comment: Is it possible for you @Shijin to explain a little bit of this code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest of solutions is to activate Mage_XmlConnect module, from 1.9.1.0 this module is inactive by default. You can activate this module by modifying

> app/etc/modules/Mage_XmlConnect.xml

change the value of `<active>` tag from **false** to **true**

Comment: doesn't help. At least not on Magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: Works on Magento 1.9.2.2. You can again disable the Module aftwerwards.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with 1.9, but managed to solve it by manually insert the attribute directly into DB. Check the following 3 tables **eav_attribute** , **catalog_eav_attribute** , **eav_entity_attribute** for the `image` attribute (mine has the id 45) and duplicate it accordingly to thumbnail. Hope this will help.